# How to find the standard error of a sample of measurements each with their own uncertainity

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-error, measurement-error

I have a scale that has a resolution of +-0.01 grams. I have assumed that it has a standard error of +-0.005 grams. I would like to measure the mass of an Samsung INR18650-30Q battery. I would like to estimate the average battery's weight because I am building a battery pack with a couple of thousand of these battery cells. I have measured three of them and their measurements are as follows...
1) 46.08 +-0.005 grams
2) 45.99 +-0.005 grams
3) 45.96 +-0.005 grams

*How would I find the mean and standard error of the population given that each measurements has an uncertainty of +-0.005 grams?*

**------- What I've done so far --------**
I have found the standard deviation which is 0.06245 (4 sf) and calculated the standard error using

SE=(standard deviation)/SQRT(Number of samples) which gives an SE of 0.0361 (4 sf).

I've also found the error propagation of averaging three measured values.
 SE_P=SQRT(3*(0.005)^2)/3 which is 0.002887 (4 sf).

How can I combine the uncertainty that exists in the manufacture of each battery and the uncertainty of my scale?

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/394178/calculating-standard-error-of-the-mean-when-we-have-uncertainties-for-each-measu) post but I'm not sure if it answers my question, as it finds the standard error when another measurement is made.

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: According to the [spec](https://eu.nkon.nl/sk/k/30q.pdf), it's 48g max and typically 45.6g. Don't expect a better precision on 3 points.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! I was going to take more measurements however I was wanting to understand the process of calculating uncertainty before going ahead and taking hundreds of measurements. How would you find the uncertainty?